# Passing 'key' dynamically in 'key=value' type parameter

Tags: python, dictionary

I had this following rough code snippet.

```
param={'a':1,'b':2}
for k,v in param.items():
     func2(k=v)
```

func2 is defined as:

```
func2(**kwargs):
    print kwargs.get('a',None)
    print kwargs.get('b',None)
```

When func2() is called the variable 'k' is being passed instead of it's value.How to  pass k's value to func2(**kwargs) ?

Comment: @Christian: Not `func2(param)`. Possibly `func2(**param)`, depending on what the OP really wants to make happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`**` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
for k, v in param.items():
     func2(**{k: v})
```

Comment: @martineau, No, they are not equivalent. The code in the answer will call twice for the given `param`. `func2(a=1)`, `func2(b=2)`.